# Multiple Regex on a single request

Tags: javascript

I wrote an app that shows last posts through API, and I'm using a regex to strip HTML tags from the result (that is actually plain text).

```
post.contentHtml retrieve the last post
```

example retrieved: `"hi this is my last post <b>with</b> some html tags"`

so my line is:

```
 post.contentHtml().replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '')
```

example retrieved: `"hi this is my last post with some html tags"`

Now sometimes users post text with image URLs, and I want to replace all image URLs with a FontAwesome icons.

Is this possible with JavaScript?

Comment: It is indeed possible. Not with plain text, however. It's also not clear how that is related to your title.

Comment: actually i'm using the regex that u see in the post....but i want also to replace image urls with fontawesome icon....is that not clear? sorry but i'm not english

Comment: So.... why can't you run a *separate* regex that finds the image URLs and replaces them with icons?

Comment: my question is if is possible to concatenate regexp into my line (example in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution by myself:

since i do not know how to replace with rendered html (actually if i put html it returns literally, i can do this with a text icon:

```
post.contentHtml().replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '').replace(/(https?:\/\/\S+(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif))/g, '')
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to use match with regex. The sample is given below.

**Regex:**
`/<[^>]*>/g`

Note: You can make a more complex regex.

```js
const str = 'hi this is <img src="test" /> my  <span>with1</span> last post <b>with2</b> some html tags';
console.log(str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ""))
```

Comment: The regex can also be like `/<(\w+)>(.+?)<\/\1>/g`

Comment: not sure that this will help to catch image urls and replace with fontawesome icon

Comment: @GhostOps: Yes true.. i almost forget.

Comment: @MarkoColia: Updated my regex solution. This will take care of img tag too